# jQuery on "selected option" select

Tags: jquery, events

It's easy to listen to select's change:

```
var redirect = function() {
    return window.location = $(this).val();
};

$('body').on('change', '#nav-select', redirect);
```

But how about catching the selection of an already selected option (no `change` event for us)?

Tried:

```
$('body').on('click', '#nav-select option', redirect);
```

doesn't work...

EDIT: to be clear:

I have a select with default selected option `foo`. I want to catch this:

1. user clicks on select
2. selects the option `foo`, which is already selected (no change event)

Comment: You mean if the select loaded with an option selected?

Answer (score 1):

So I interpreted your question as:

*"How can I run code when an option is clicked but the select element's value did not change"*

My solution was to store the initial value from the option that the select loads with. Then attach a spinning lock to the select element. Then attach a click event which is controlled by the spinning lock. Then see if the click was on the option which was initially loaded. Here is the result:

working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NS4qr/3/

html

```
<select id="s1">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="3">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

js

```
$(function(){
    (function(){
        var loadedOption = $("#s1 option:selected").val();
        var isOpen = false;

        $("#s1").blur(function(){
            isOpen = false;
        });

        $("#s1").click(function(){
            isOpen = !isOpen;
            if(isOpen)return;
            if(this.value == loadedOption){
             //window.location = $(this).val();
             alert($(this).val());
            }
        });
    })();
});
```

Comment: @PetrMarek - What part didn't work? For me, when the page loads it is selected on "asjfasafsasf". Nothing happens. I click on the dropdown, nothing happens. I click on asjfasafsasf, and it alerts 0.

Comment: Clicking on selected `asjfasafsasf` works only every even time. Strange.

Comment: @PetrMarek - There is an edge case where a user may open the dropdown and then drag their mouse out and then release (not over the select option). This will cause the event to not fire because it did not hit the click event since the mouseup event was outside of the select element.

Comment: Not really. I click the select, click the selected option and nothing happens. Do the exact same thing the second time and bang! there's an alert.

Comment: @PetrMarek - Your results are not repeatable. I had several others test and were unable to reproduce your findings.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify "click" handler for option element in jQuery and you can trigger a "click" event on an option element, also using jQuery, which would then invoke your "click" handler.

However, there is no "click" event on option elements, so actually clicking on it (with a mouse) will not create click event. It will create "change" event on the select element, but only if you clicked on an option that wasn't selected.

Example:

```
<select id="testSelect">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#testSelect option").click(function (event) {
        console.log("option clicked");
    });

    $("#testSelect option[value='2']").click(); // console outputs "option clicked"
</script>
```

Comment: I know that (see the question), that's why I am asking if there's an other way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can try using "focus" event and get/save the selected value at that point. Later in "change" event handler you can catch if the selection changes and update the saved value.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use "select" and "click" together. Something like

```
$('body').on('change', '#nav-select', redirect);

$('body').on('click', '#nav-select option', redirect);
```

Comment: Have you read the question completely? I've written exactly the same line stating, that it doesn't work.

Comment: oops, sorry! I meant click on select, not option!